# Creating a derivation tree from a set of Grammar rules

Tags: java, parsing, tree, context-free-grammar

I have 2 arrays, defining a set of rules in a Context free grammar. With array 1 being the left Side of a rule and array 2 being the right side of a rule, for example :

```
A = B | C would translate to array1[0] = A, array2[0] = B C
```

From this, I want to construct all the possible derivation given an integer that defines how many steps can occur. So for example, A ---> C would constitute 1 step. If the integer would be 3, a program would print out all the possible derivations that occur in 3 steps.

Any advice on how to tackle this program would be appreciated, I've been trying to think a way around the problem for hours with no success. I'm using Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using String objects to express derivations you could use your starting symbol and split its derivation using the delimiter " ". Then you could search for derivations for the non-terminals in the right order and try to recursively derive them.
If there are only terminals left, you could print out the complete derivation which you have stored in a structure, e. g. a list, which contains every derivation.
Then you get back to the last point where still other options are available to derive.

But I think your modelling is not that good since this is not really efficient. The problem you are dealing with is typically solved by parser implementations which are also used e. g. for compiler implementation. Have a look at this resource (wikipedia): [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).
There are two main approaches: Top-down- and bottom-up-parsing.